# How do I send a variable in jquery to a callback function? function(r){ }

Tags: jquery, function, variables, callback

How do I send a variable in jquery to a callback function? function(r){ }

[Look at the demo](http://fresherplay.tk/stock/)

Whilst on the demo, notice that the form above the menu can be serialised. Also notice that when clicking a folder icon whilst on an item (click a category from the left), and submit the form that way, it cannot be serialised.

I have a variable which I need to be passed to the callback function, if that's what it's called; to the **function(r) { }** section of the code.

Below is the code that works that's above the header.

```
<?php $moveablecats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id != '1'  "); ?><form id="changecategoryForm2"><select id="newflex" name="thecatidichose"> <option value=""></option> <?php while($catrow =mysql_fetch_array($moveablecats)){ ?> <option value="<?php echo "$catrow[id]"; ?>"><?php echo "$catrow[title]"; ?> </option><?php } ?></select>  </form>   <p><tt id="results"></tt></p>


<script>
    function showValues() {
      var str = $("form#changecategoryForm2").serialize();
      $("#results").text(str);
    }
    $(":checkbox, :radio").click(showValues);
    $("select").change(showValues);
    showValues();
</script>
```

Below is the code that does not work. I am using the [jquery alerts dialogs plugin][2].
Ignore the lines that are commented out.
When the script alerts the serialised form, it is blank, so it does not work. It does however manage to show the **itemid** and **categoryid** variable.

```
$(".changecategory").click( function() {
   <?php $moveablecats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id != '1'  "); ?>
 var categoryid = $(this).attr("categoryid");
 var itemid = $(this).attr("itemid");
 var itemid2 = $(this).attr("itemid");
 var itemtitle = $(this).attr("itemtitle");
 var parenttag = $(this).parent().get(0).tagName;
 var removediv = "itemid_" +itemid;

   jAlert(
      'Which category do you want to move <b>'+itemtitle+ '</b> to?<br><?php $moveablecats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id != '1'  "); ?><form id="changecategoryForm"><select id="newflex" name="thecatidichose"> <option value=""></option> <?php while($catrow =mysql_fetch_array($moveablecats)){ ?> <option value="<?php echo "$catrow[id]"; ?>"><?php echo "$catrow[title]"; ?> </option><?php } ?></select>  </form>   <p><tt id="results"></tt></p>','Change category', function(r) {
         // $(parenttag).fadeOut('slow');  
         $("#"+removediv).fadeOut('slow');  

         //var newflex = $("#newflex").val();
   //alert(newflex);

   alert($("#changecategoryForm").serialize());
   //alert('categoryid ' + categoryid + ' itemid ' + itemid + '.');

   //var dataString = $("#changecategoryForm").serialize();
   /*
   //remember to add validation for blank fields

   $("#loading4").show();
   $("#loading4").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="loading.gif">');

   var newrow = "134";
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "formcontrols.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
     $("#creation4").after(html);
     $("#loading4").hide();
     //$("#newrow").before($('itembeforehere'));
    }
   });
   */
   //
   return false;


         jAlert(''+ itemtitle +' has been successfully moved.', 'Success');
      }
   ); 


});
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, and ideally create a much, much simplified example of what you're trying to do? It's very hard to answer this question in its current form.

Comment: do you have two forms, changecategoryForm2 and changecategoryForm or is that a typo?

Comment: I have 2 forms. 1 form is the one at the top of the screen. The other one, you will see when you register to the website, choose a category on the left, then click a folder icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for a [**closure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)), but it's really hard to tell from your question. Here's a *simple* example of a closure:

```
function showLater(msg, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(msg);
    }, delay);
}
```

Think of the function we're passing to `setTimeout` as the callback. When you call `showLater`:

```
showLater("Hi there", 2000);
```

...it returns right away, but the anonymous closure still has access to the arguments you gave to `showLater`, so that when it gets run a couple of seconds later, it can do the "Hi there" alert.

One uses closures a lot when dealing with ajax calls and the like, since by default (and by preference) they're asynchronous. (I simulated that asynchronicity above using `setTimeout`, to keep things simple.)

[More on closures here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).